# Tools to detect False Sharing in a C/C++ application

Tags: c++, c, false-sharing

Are there any tools that detect and report [False Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) for applications written in C or C++?

Comment: while not showing _false_ sharing directly, intel vtunes can at least on certain CPUs detect sharing, but it costs money and is hard to interpret the result.

Comment: Intel products have a personal use license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Sheriff and Predator. 
Sheriff is at https://github.com/plasma-umass/sheriff, while Predator is at https://github.com/plasma-umass/Predator.
Predator is a compiler-based approach that you have to recompile your program using a new LLVM compiler. It is the most exhaustive detection tool up to now. 
Sheriff is library but it can only detect false sharing if you are using pthreads library.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [DRD](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html) (data race detection) module of valgrind.

From the manual it looks like it can be used to detect False sharing.

Comment: Unfortunately, DRD does not detect anything, even in the simplest cases of false sharing such the one described on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing

Comment: Actually, in the manual there is no claim that DRD is able to detect false sharing

Answer (score 1):

Perf("Performance Counters for Linux")

Commands:

```
sudo perf record -e cache-misses,anything_else_you_want ./your_program 
sudo perf report
```